# Difference between SCORM 1.2 and SCORM 2004

Tags: moodle, scorm, scorm2004, scorm1.2

What are the core differences between SCORM 1.2 and SCORM 2004?

I have to publish my elearning course to SCORM and then upload to moodle. but there are two version of SCORM 1.2 and 2004. I am getting confused which one should be used to upload course on moodle.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

There are a number of additional features of SCORM 2004 including some additional tracking fields and sequencing and navigation capability. However, many tools that publish to SCORM 2004 don't actually take advantage of these features and just send the same data as they would with SCORM 1.2. Further, Moodle's built in SCORM module only has partial support for SCORM 2004.

My advice: unless you have a specific reason to use SCORM 2004, use SCORM 1.2.

Comment: Scorm 2004 is a lot nicer with what's permitted and saved, but it really does come down to what's being saved from the course - have a look at the Run-Time Reference docs to see the sheer size of the difference - http://scorm.com/scorm-explained/technical-scorm/run-time/run-time-reference/ - the biggest issue is more likely to be Moodle and the problems of trying to get anything other than 1.2 running on it...

Comment: thanks. I found scorm 2004 more flexible and helpful for lms interaction.

Comment: I'd say Andy's advice is Moodle specific.   If your LMS supports 2004 well, there are a few compelling reasons why you would want to use it as your publishing standard.   At the top of the list [but not the only item] is the SCORM 1.2 bookmark is limited to 1024 characters, which can be easily overrun in many scenarios.

Comment: It's also 2015 specific to a certain extent :-) 6 years on, I'd be questioning why you've not migrated to xAPI by now.